# jQuery sortable save issue

Tags: jquery, arrays, jquery-ui-sortable

I have below function to save my sortable portlet in database.
When I save the sorted order, the variable order which has an array of portlet in the respective column gives me hard time.
Actually it should return me the value of array but in console or even in database when i try to save it it saves as a 'Array' as string not the value word 'Array'

```
function saveOrder() {
  $(".column").each(function(index, value){
    var colid = value.id;
    var order = $('#' + colid).sortable("toArray");
    for ( var i = 0, n = order.length; i < n; i++ ) {
       var v = $('#' + order[i] ).find('.portlet-content').attr('collapse');
       var h = $(this).find(".portlet").is(':visible');
       if (typeof v=="undefined") { v = "0"; }
          order[i] = order[i] + ":" + v + ":" + h;
     }
     $.ajax({ 
        type: "post",
        url: "save.php", 
        data: {
           order_status: order,
           order_Id: colid,
           username: <?php echo $username; ?>
         },
    dataType: 'json', 
        success:  function(data) { console.log(data); alert('sent successfully.'); }
     });  
});
```

I am really stuck and early response will be very much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should encode the object in JSON before sending like this:

```
$.ajax({ 
        type: "post",
        url: "save.php", 
        data: "data=" + JSON.stringify({
             order_status: order,
             order_Id: colid,
             username: <?php echo '"', $username, '"'; ?>
        }),
```

and in server save.php script use

```
$post_data = json_decode($_POST['data']);
```

Does this help?

Comment: @Nimmi On the javascript or php side?

Comment: @Nimmi maybe it's the problem $username encoding. It's not very nice but everything should work. You should get a nice object in PHP side.

Comment: any idea on how i can access the value of $username variable with jquery? will json_encode help?

Comment: I have skipped array for now without array as i m behind with my deadline.